# Unable to sign with Smartcard through Java app after my machine has has slept: getting a PKCS11Exception: CKR_GENERAL_ERROR

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, smartcard, pkcs#11

I have an application that performs digital signatures with a smartcard. If my system sleeps and later wakes (both windows and mac), my invocations to `signature.sign` start blowing up with a `sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_GENERAL_ERROR` ProviderException from then on

Do you have any idea of how should I get my program to sign again without this pesky error?

Comment: What PKCS#11 library do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that it is possible to recover from this error by removing the card from the card reader, attempting to sign again without having any card in the cardreader (thus intentionally failing) and later putting the card in the cardreader and try to sign again.

As this behaviour depends on removing the card, the way I am handling the error is by requesting the user to take out and put in the card at certain moments.